# Morphological operation to improve the shape of segmented image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, mathematical-morphology

I have an ellipse in the image.After segmentation i got a broken ellipse as shown .which morphological operation is used to get the perfect ellipse [image]

Actual input file is
[image]

output obtained is
[image]

i tried imopen ,but i will lose lower ellipse like structure .how to close the upper ellipse like structure without losing lower ones

Mask i created is
[image]

i want to segment the ellipse like structure.but some of these structures are connected with rectangular like bodies.how to separate it. erode will eliminate small ellipses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reconnect something with a mathematical morphology operator, do not use an opening (it increases the gap), but a closing (imclose)! The names are explicits.

In you case, you want to reconnect something vertically cut, so use a horizontal structuring element (type segment).

And yes, you have to invert your image, black pixels representing the absence of information.

Comment: i didnt understand segment.can you give me a small example

Comment: Usually most of people use structuring element with a shape of type square or disk. But you can use whatever shape you want, as segments or hexagon (this one is loved by the experts because of its particular topology). For example, when you want to perform a quick erosion using a square, you perform an erosion with a vertical segment, and then an other erosion with a horizontal segment. You have an example here: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/09/25/dilation-erosion-and-the-morphological-gradient/

Comment: You also have plenty of examples here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#morphology

Comment: And here are the original courses, by one of the guy who invented mathematical morphology (Jean Serra): http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~serra/cours/index.htm

Comment: i added mask.please suggest some method to separate ellipse like structure from the rectangular structures esp the one at the top

Comment: I am not sure which structures you are talking about into you image. Could you point them? If you want to filter the ellipse like shapes patterns in the middle of many patterns, I used to use the shape indexes. However to do so, you need to first separate the different patterns.

Comment: i need ellipse like structure.can you explain a little bit about shape indexes.i'm a beginner

Comment: Here is a paper about shape indexes, including two shape indexes dedicated to ellipse characterization: http://www.thibault.biz/Doc/Publications/PosterWSCG2008_Article.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for closing gaps, you would need the close operator.
However, since most software assume active pixels are white, you would either need to invert the image, or use the open operator.
On this image, in matlab, the following works well:

```
imopen(I,ones(32))
```

This uses a square structuring element.  You may want to experiment with other shapes.

Your example also looks like you moved half of the ellipse, as opposed to some process which deleted pixels in the middle.  No simple morphological operation can create a `perfect` ellipse out of the sample image, unless you use the knowledge that multiple components can be moved to re-form the ellipse.  If that is the actual case, you can scan connected components and try to match them together.

Comment: added actual input file and its segmented  output

Comment: For such input images, you'll probably get better results by using other techniques on the gray image, before you lose too much information.  Try MSER.

Comment: i didnt got better result using MSER