# I need to create a 3D sphere from a bunch of 2D slices

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d

I currently have to create a sphere from a stack of 2D slices (2D matrices in MATLAB, which represent 2D gray scale images). I have created a bunch of slices using the code below. To create the sphere I have repeatedly created slices of circles of increasing size till 100, and  then of decreasing sizes. All of these slices are added to a 3D matrix.

```
Circle = ones(200,400,400); 

for i = 1:100
    [rr cc] = meshgrid(1:400);
    C = sqrt((rr-200).^2+(cc-200).^2)<=i;
    for j = 1:400
        for k = 1:400
            Circle(i,j,k) = C(j,k);
        end
    end
end

index = 100; 

for i = 1:100
    [rr cc] = meshgrid(1:400);
    C = sqrt((rr-200).^2+(cc-200).^2)<=index;
    for j = 1:400
        for k = 1:400
            Circle(i+100,j,k) = C(j,k);
        end
    end
    index = index - 1; 
end

viewer3d(Circle);
```

`viewer3d` is  3rd part library that helps you view your 3D image stacks of slices as 3d objects. Once I visualized this 'supposed' sphere, I realized that it is a diamond shape top and not a sphere.

Therefore I do not understand how to vary the size of circles till the center point of the sphere in the `y` plane and then decrease it with the same algorithm.

Thank you for your answers and please do not hesitate to ask me to clarify anything within this question.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant [\[slice\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/slice/info) tag from your question. Please read the tag descriptions before posting, in order to make sure that a tag means what you think it means:) Also, you can create a decreasing for loop with `for i=100:-1:1`, more generally look at what `100:-1:1` is.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I had forgotten about the `for i=100:-1:1`! Thanks for reminding me! I was talking about a slice in the rough sense of the tag description, but a scientific slice instead. The tag removal however was justified!

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, you are welcome to retag your question:) That's also the reason I left a comment: you can judge its correctness.

Comment: I just wanted to also note that your question asking skills, and MATLAB skills as well, have improved a lot:) I'm glad to see you advancing, and keep it up!

Comment: @AndrasDeak, you remember me! Thank you by the way, I have been working with a University as a researcher and have been using a lot of MATLAB for my image processing. All credit to the MATLAB community on SO, that's been helping me along the way though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, create a sphere directly, without using loops:

```
Circle = zeros(200,400,400); 

[x,y,z]=meshgrid(1:size(Circle,1),1:size(Circle,2),1:size(Circle,3));

radius=??; %// e.g. radius=100;
%//this sphere is centered in the middle of the image
Circle(sqrt((x-size(Circle,1)/2).^2+(y-size(Circle,2)/2).^2..
     +(z-size(Circle,2)/2).^2)<radius)=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the radius along the Z axis is not linear but varies with cos/sin function. Using [this representation](http://www.derivations.org/sphere.png):

[image: http://www.derivations.org/sphere.png]

your radius is "Radius = r sin(Theta)", with "Theta = arccos(r / z)". So "r" is the radius of your sphere, and "z" the level/slice you want to draw in. Don't forget to that "z" goes from -"r" to "r". I've tested the formulae and it works fine for an image stack (slices).

Comment: This is not a good answer. It is not at all clear how exactly OP should apply your note. Don't forget that if OP had firm maths backgrounds (necessary to decypher your note), he wouldn't have had the problem in the first place. In its current form your answer should rather be a comment.

Comment: @AndrasDeak haha, I kind of feel like my mathematics skills aren't up to your expectations!

Comment: @SharanDuggirala I didn't mean to offend you:) On the contrary, I left this comment for FiReTiTi for your sake, I might not have found it useful in your place.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: if my answer is understandable or not detailed enough, he can simply ask me for more details. I've edited and tested it.

Comment: @FiReTiTi I admit that I probably wouldn't have commented on this answer alone. However, I've seen this recurring pattern: you answer an image-processing question with the \[[tag:matlab]\] tag, but in vague/pseudocode terms, often leading to confusion (see for instance [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34457952/5067311)). I suspect that you're simply unfamiliar with MATLAB, and this is why you're reluctant to give readily usable, code-based answers. This is not necessarily a problem, but I believe you should express your non-code answers in a way that is most easily digestible to others.

Comment: Indeed, i don't use matlab because it is too slow for my needs. So I prefer give a pseudo-code than using a specific language that the poster may not know.

Comment: @FiReTiTi if you *do* know matlab, I encourage you to give code-based answers whenever the [matlab] tag is present, and the question contains matlab code:) I'm sure it would be beneficial both to the poster, and to Stack Overflow in general. (That's all, I'll stop bugging you now.)